# Doctrine 2 Spatial Data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mysql-spatial

I am having extreme difficulty making this doctrine2 extension works. 
It is https://github.com/djlambert/doctrine2-spatial and theres not a lot of doc on how to create a polygon. I got the config file working and all but I am struggling with creating the actual polygon.

```
array:564 [
   0 => array:2 [
    0 => -73.698313
    1 => 45.546876
   ]
   1 => array:2 [
     0 => -73.69813
     1 => 45.546916
   ]
   2 => array:2 [
     0 => -73.697656
     1 => 45.546899
   ]
    3 => array:2 [
      0 => -73.697413
      1 => 45.546899
   ]

 $poly = new Polygon($array);

[CrEOF\Spatial\Exception\InvalidValueException]  
  Invalid Polygon Point value of type "double"
```

This is the actual error Im getting. I tried creating points instead because apparently it doesn't like doubles.

```
$p = new Point($coord);
$temp[] = $p;
$poly = new Polygon($temp);


[CrEOF\Spatial\Exception\InvalidValueException]                                    
  Invalid Polygon LineString value of type      "CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\Point"
```

After that, I was like ok, lets create a line string object and pass it.

```
$line = new LineString($points);
$poly - new Polygon($line);

 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                           
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to    CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\AbstractPolygon::__construct() must be of the type array,   object given, called in /Library/Web        Server/Documents/mg/src/Momoa/ImmobilierBundle/Entity/geography/Quartier.php on line 131 and defined
```

Im just lost right now, the only thing I wanted was to store polygons in the database and call spatial functions such as `CONTAINS`. Do you have any recommendation or such other things to make all of this work.

After digging through the source code I found this validate function which seems to be the problem

```
case (is_array($point) && count($point) == 2 && is_numeric($point[0]) &&    is_numeric($point[1])):
            return array_values($point);
            break;
        default:
            throw InvalidValueException::invalidType($this, GeometryInterface::POINT, $point);
    }
```

The way I'm understanding this is that the extension do not accept points that have decimal values ?! Huh, Does that mean I need to convert my coordinates to 2 integers ?!

Answer (score 6):

I will post the solution I found. Basically you need to create your polygon like this

```
$line = new LineString($coords);
$poly = new Polygon(array($line));
//Or you can do it like this
$coords[0] = $coords;
$poly = new Polygon($coords);
//Following if you wanna use MBRContains or Contains
$dql = "SELECT p FROM polygon p WHERE MBRContains(p.geometry, GeomFromText('Point($lat $lng)'))=1";
//Dont use GeomFromText(:point), and then $point = new Point(array($lat,$lng));
```

Basically good luck guys, that library is useful but the documentation is BAD !
Spent the whole day on that yesterday !!

Comment: You're right about the documentation. I want to use it for unserializion from JSON file and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it by passing data in constructor.
But the problem is that you should have a valid polygon data:

`$p = new Polygon([[[lat1, lng1], [lat2, lng2], [lat3, lng3], [lat1, lng2]]]);`

Be sure that in the Polygon

1. there are three arrays — array of lines, where line is an array of points, where every point is an array.
2. the path is closed — the last point equals to the first one.

The same truth for MultiPolygon but + one more array. F.e.
`[[[["32.699005219026645","-117.18222600929262"],["32.694563070816095","-117.18437177650453"],["32.697687043641835","-117.17149717323305"],["32.699005219026645","-117.18222600929262"]]]]`